# find the URL after button click from the website using selenium python

Tags: python, selenium, url, selenium-firefoxdriver

Every Button of the website may contain the link, for the below website how to find out URL appears in next tab.

wants to print and scrape the URL after the button click
am using firefox web driver

```
driver.get("https://www.dove.com/us/en/skin-care/body-lotion/cream-oil-intensive-body-lotion.html")
driver.find_element_by_xpath("//span[contains(text(),'Ingredients')]").click()
time.sleep(3)
driver.find_element_by_xpath("//button[contains(text(),'Go to SmartLabel™')]").click()
```

Comment: Check my answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should be easy, just use `driver.current_url`. So with your code you could try

```
driver.get("https://www.dove.com/us/en/skin-care/body-lotion/cream-oil-intensive-body-lotion.html")
driver.find_element_by_xpath("//span[contains(text(),'Ingredients')]").click()
time.sleep(3)
driver.find_element_by_xpath("//button[contains(text(),'Go to SmartLabel™')]").click()
time.sleep(5)
driver.switch_to.window(driver.window_handles[1])

print(driver.current_url)
```

Comment: Oh, I figured out the problem from looking at the website. the "Go to SmartLabel" button opens a new tab, and you will need to tell Selenium to switch to that tab. Give me a minute and I'll update my answer with how to do that.

Comment: yeah is that any other way to find out the link?

Answer (score 0):

I saw few problems:

1 **Waits**. Get rid of time.sleep(). Replace it with explicit/implicit waits. I observed that these elements are the last that are loaded on the page: `picture[class='loaded']`. So, I added wait for them.

2 **To switch** between tabs use: `driver.switch_to.window(driver.window_handles[1])`, `driver.switch_to.window(driver.window_handles[0])` - to switch to initial tab.

**Solution for Chrome**

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.wait import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC


driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path='/snap/bin/chromium.chromedriver')
# driver.implicitly_wait(10)
driver.get("https://www.dove.com/us/en/skin-care/body-lotion/cream-oil-intensive-body-lotion.html")
wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 30)
wait.until(EC.visibility_of_all_elements_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "picture[class='loaded']")))
wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR, ".collapsed>a[title='Ingredients']")))
driver.find_element_by_css_selector(".collapsed>a[title='Ingredients']").click()
wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//button[contains(text(),'Go to SmartLabel')]")))
driver.find_element_by_xpath("//button[contains(text(),'Go to SmartLabel')]").click()
driver.switch_to.window(driver.window_handles[1])
print(driver.current_url)
driver.close()
driver.switch_to.window(driver.window_handles[0])
print(driver.current_url)
```

Output:

```
https://smartlabel.unileverusa.com/011111375512-0001-en-US/index.html
https://www.dove.com/us/en/skin-care/body-lotion/cream-oil-intensive-body-lotion.html
```

For **Firefox** you'll need to wait for at least one element on the second page, otherwise the output will not give you expected link:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.wait import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC


driver = webdriver.Firefox()
driver.implicitly_wait(10)
driver.get("https://www.dove.com/us/en/skin-care/body-lotion/cream-oil-intensive-body-lotion.html")
wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 30)
wait.until(EC.visibility_of_all_elements_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "picture[class='loaded']")))
wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR, ".collapsed>a[title='Ingredients']")))
driver.find_element_by_css_selector(".collapsed>a[title='Ingredients']").click()
wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//button[contains(text(),'Go to SmartLabel')]")))
driver.find_element_by_xpath("//button[contains(text(),'Go to SmartLabel')]").click()
driver.switch_to.window(driver.window_handles[1])
wait.until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, ".container-fluid.content-section")))
print(driver.current_url)
driver.close()
driver.switch_to.window(driver.window_handles[0])
print(driver.current_url)
```

P.S. If you are looking for a way to find links by attribute names, there is no way because this button does not have such. The link is generated.

Comment: 1. OP is using Firefox, not Chrome; it will probably work, but still. 2. While the waits are a good suggestion, they don't actually address OP's original problem. Moreover, since `wait` returns a webElement so you can write `wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//button[contains(text(),'Go to SmartLabel')]"))).click()` to avoid some extra lines (and slow xpaths)

Comment: 1. Added solution for Firefox 2. I doubt that the time will be significantly slower, I doubt it will even be slower. Moreover, it addresses their problem in full because site may not load in 3 seconds and `Ingredients` tab may be unclickable. `time.sleep()` is the last thing we should use.

Comment: I agree, hard waits are a last resort or just something to put in place until you get proper dynamic waits worked out.

Comment: To switch between tabs window_handles[1]  window_handles[0])  is the right way but explicit/implicit waits throwing errors.

Comment: On which row do you see error? You already can upvote answers, so please do so if they are helpful.